# Simple If/else statement

Tags: if-statement

Revised Code of full deal.. instead of just the small snippet.. Would $row be the start of the variable?

```
 <?php
   error_reporting(-1);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM products Where available like 'Y%'  order by manufacturer2, product ASC";
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
```

<--------------------->>
        $new_product = "$row";  if ($new_product == "N") 
        {     echo "No"; } elseif ($new_product == "Y") 
         {     echo "Yes"; }

```
<-------->


     echo "<div class=reportsalesnew_product>".$row['new_product']."</div>";
     echo "<div class=reportsalescase_avail>".$row['case_avail']."</div>";
     echo "<div class=reportsalesseasonal>".$row['seasonal']."</div>";
     echo "<div class=reportsaleseigth_bbl>".$row['eigth_bbl']."</div>";
     echo "<div class=reportsalesquarter_bbl>".$row['quarter_bbl']."</div>";
     echo "<div class=reportsaleshalf_bbl>".$row['half_bbl']."</div>";
     echo "<div class=reportsalessixth_bbl>".$row['sixth_bbl']."</div>";
     echo "<div class=reportsalesthirty_liter>".$row['thirty_liter']."</div>";
     echo "<div class=reportsalesfifty_liter>".$row['fifty_liter']."</div>";


      echo "</div>";
      }

       ?>
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Condition you declared is wrong, instead of ($new_product = "N") use ($new_product == "N") - double equals

Comment: I changed the = to == and now I am not getting an error or anything being displayed..

Comment: I am getting an Notice: Undefined variable: new_product

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is `PHP`, use the `==` for [equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) checks. If you **also** want to do type checks use the `===` (recommended).

Also, you might want to look at the [`boolean`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) data type for this, this is a simple `true`/`false`.

Comment: I am getting an Notice: Undefined variable: new_product

Answer (score 0):

Everyone accidentally does it when they begin programming. You've wrote one ='s sign to check for equality but all that is doing is assign it therefore it will always be true(unless it's a constant). Use two ='s for equality, three '='s for type, one '=' for an assignment.

Comment: I am a hack .. :) BUT I changed it to == and it now displays nothing? that was the original problem I thought I was closer to the solution by using the single =..

Comment: I am getting an Notice: Undefined variable: new_product

Comment: means that you havn't defined $new_product, like $new_product = 'bob';

Comment: Why would I need to do that? new_product is the field that the information is coming from.. Maybe I am not getting or trying to do something the wrong way..

Comment: if there is a Y in the field data I would like to display a color if there is an N in the field data i would like to display another color.

Comment: maybe you've jumped the gun a little, try this : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Comment: try apply that to your problem, and use simpler things than echo <div>.. etc just to test.. e.g  echo "First option"

Comment: So i think I am having a problem defining the variable. I understand that if ($new_product == "Y") {
  echo "Have a good day!";
} But it needs the variable??  >>>>> $new_product=WHAT("Y");

Comment: i don't know what is defining your $new_product but yes, you need to define that $new_product, i don't know how you are trying to assign $new_product

Comment: I am not understanding the logic then.. I have a field new_product that either has a Y or an N in it data wise. What I would like is if there is a Y, I would like to display something specific to the Y, If there is an N I would like to display something specific to the N.   .......------ Sorry I am not getting this I am sure this is easy PHP maybe I don't need an if statement and I need something else..

Comment: I'm not sure really either, could I see more of it? Primarily how the $new_product is being assigned

Comment: your code is fine, i don't know what the issue is.. look try online:

Comment: $new_product = "Y";

if ($new_product == "N") {
    echo "<div class=reportsalesnew_product>No</div>";
} elseif ($new_product == "Y") {
    echo "<div class=reportsalesnew_product>Yes</div>";
}

Comment: http://writecodeonline.com/php/  try it on there, and change Y and N in the top variable

Comment: Maybe what your struggling with is the concept of how to make $new_product be your new product?

Comment: So that code doesn't give any errors but it only displays all yes and the straight results are just N except for one Yes in the database..

Comment: yes, and if you change the $new_product = "Y"; to N, itll be the opposite. you have to find a way to assign $new_product correctly to your problem

Comment: I think that is the confusing part for me.. ? I am pulling the data from the field new_product..

Comment: so ideally your $new_product should be like $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link); $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: then you write a var called i, assign it as 0, and then run it to the max amount of rows ie like while(i<$num_rows){ ..select row (i) and get new_product, then display here your code above then you're done }

Comment: but as I say, you're really jumping the gun, try learn mysql and php from books or online tutorials before you go ahead. your problem is very, very common and you'll come across it

Comment: I have put my full code at the top.. $row is defined in the while statement in my original code..

Comment: you've put $row in quotes, thta means it literally takes the variable the four characters inside the quotes-"$row", so tehrefore it'll never be N or Y. do $new_product = $row;

Comment: OK.. did that and now I don't get an error but I don't get any output.... ---- Appreciate the time on this you are being beyond patient with me..

Comment: just try echo $row; inside the loop, remove everything else, do you just get YYYYNYNYN or whatever?

Comment: I get ..  Notice: Undefined index: row